# MVVM binding content control from observablecollection of views

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm, observablecollection

I am attempting to populate a ScrollerViewer control with an arbitrary number of of UserControls (Views) whilst using the MVVM pattern and bindings.

I am using an ObservableCollection to maintain my View collection and I have this collection set as the datacontext for my ScrollViewer control, however, getting the views to appear in the scroll viewer has had me going round in circles for a while now.

Can someone please point me to either a suitable example, or kindly provide an example which demonstrates the functionality I am attempting to achieve here?

Many thanks,

Comment: Why don't you post some of your more relevant code and what problem you're having?  That might help narrow things down a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I think you want an ItemsControl, not a ScrollViewer.  Once you do that, assuming that your ObservableCollection of viewmodels is called "Items":

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <uc:MyControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Replace the `<uc:MyControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>` with a reference to your UserControl.

Comment: This question had little to do with my question.  But this answer is spot on.  Cheers!